# Spring Batch CSV to Mongodb - 100s of columns

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch

I am very new to Java and have been tasked to use spring batch to read in some text files. So far Spring batch resources online have helped me to get to a point where I am reading, processing and writing some simple test `.csv` files into Mongo.

The problem I have now is that the actual file I would like to read from has over 600 columns. Meaning that with the current way I am reading in my file to Java, I would need 600+ fields in my @Document mongo model.

I have been thinking of a couple of ways to get around this,
first I was thinking maybe  I could read in each line as a string and then in my processor deal with splitting everything up and formatting the data to then return a list of my MongoTemplate but returning a List is not viable from the overridden process method.

So my question to you guys is,

> What is the best way to handle reading in files with hundreds of
>   columns in spring batch? Or what would be the best resource to start
>   reading to help point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem I used
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html
for reading csvs.

I suggest you use Map instead of 600 java fields.
Besides, 600X600 java strings is not a big deal for java and neither for mongo.

To manipulate with mongo use http://jongo.org/

If you really need batch processing of data.

Your flow for batches should be,

Loop here : divide in batches(say 300 per loop)

1. Read 300X300 java objects(or in a Map) from file in memory.
2. Sanitize or Process them if needed.
3. Store in mongoDB.

return if EOF.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just reading in each line as a String object. Then in the processor looping over the String object with a delimiter creating my Mongo repository objects and storing them. So I am basically doing all of the writing inside the processor method which I would say is definitely not best practice but gives me the desired end result.